# Question related to Matrices Equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

This question came in my practice paper

> If there are three square matrix A, B, C of same order satisfying the equation $A^2=A^{-1}$ and let $B=A^{2^n}$ and $C=A^{2^{(n-2)}}$ then which of the following statements are true?

> (A) det. (B – C) = 0

> (B) (B + C)(B – C) = 0

> (C) B must be equal to C

> (D) none

I did found out the answer by substituating the value of n =2 and 3 and then soving the equations
But I wanted a proof of it by solving in terms of n (i.e without value substituation)

Every Help is welcomed

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A^2=A^{-1}$$
$$A^3=I$$
$$B=A^{2^n}=A^4A^{2^{n-2}}=AC$$
A:
$$B-C=(A-I)A^{2^{n-2}}$$
Now, powers of A are invetible and not $0$, and $A-I$ can be non-zero.
B:
$$(B+C)(B-C)=(A^2-I)A^{2^{n-1}}$$
Now, powers of A are invetible and not $0$, and $A^2-I$ can be non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for your hint 
Using it I got the result  (B + C)(B – C)=(A+I)C(A-I)C. Would u plz guide on how to solve  further.

Comment: Can you think why all those factors might commute?

Comment: But there  isnt any information provided about C so how to conclude that they will commute?

Comment: We'll we lknow it's a polynomial in A?

Comment: That helped me proceed further but i again got stuck at $(B + C)(B – C)=(A^2-I)A^{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: could you find a counterexample?

Comment: Would u plz tell what did u mean by counter example

Comment: I've edited the answer to help.